# The vertical margins below and above a theorem aren't the same if the theorem begins with an enumerate list

Tags: margins, enumerate, amsthm

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, the "Solution" theorem's top and bottom margins are different. How can I make the same? I present the `LaTeX` code below.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3em,right=3em,top=3em]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Beta reduce}\quad Evaluate (that is, beta reduce) each of the following
expressions to normal form. We strongly recommend writing out the steps on
paper with a pencil or pen.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $(\lambda abc.cba)zz(\lambda wv.w)$
  \begin{sol}
    \leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $(\lambda bc.cbz)z(\lambda wv.w)$
    \item $(\lambda c.czz)(\lambda wv.w)$
    \item $(\lambda wv.w)zz$
    \item $(\lambda v.z)z$
    \item $z$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{sol}
\item $(\lambda x.\lambda y.xyy)(\lambda a.a)b$
  \begin{sol}
    \leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $(\lambda y.(\lambda a.a)yy)b$
    \item $(\lambda a.a)bb$
    \item $bb$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{sol}
\item $(\lambda y.y)(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda z.zq)$
  \begin{sol}
    \leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda z.zq)$
    \item $(\lambda z.zq)q$
    \item $qq$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{sol}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't need the  `parskip` package, remove it  -- it screws up the spacing there

Comment: I removed `parskip` and added `\noindent` at the beginning, and the top and bottom margins of the theorems became the same. If you post the answer, I'll choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `parskip` and `enumitem` do not like each other. The best is to drop the `parskip` package here. (I'll try to figure out where the real source of the problem is with `parskip`)

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3em,right=3em,top=3em]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Beta reduce}\quad Evaluate (that is, beta reduce) each of the following
expressions to normal form. We strongly recommend writing out the steps on
paper with a pencil or pen.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $(\lambda abc.cba)zz(\lambda wv.w)$

  \begin{sol}
    \leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $(\lambda bc.cbz)z(\lambda wv.w)$
    \item $(\lambda c.czz)(\lambda wv.w)$
    \item $(\lambda wv.w)zz$
    \item $(\lambda v.z)z$
    \item $z$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{sol}%\mbox{}%

\item $(\lambda x.\lambda y.xyy)(\lambda a.a)b$
  \begin{sol}
    \leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $(\lambda y.(\lambda a.a)yy)b$
    \item $(\lambda a.a)bb$
    \item $bb$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{sol}
\item $(\lambda y.y)(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda z.zq)$
  \begin{sol}
    \leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda z.zq)$
    \item $(\lambda z.zq)q$
    \item $qq$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{sol}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` disables paragraph indentation without a problem. Do you maintain parskip?

Comment: @crocket: No, I am not the maintainer. I think, the indendation is rather a enumitem option here.